# Program to Hide/show Given window with hotkey?

Tags: window-management

I'm fairly sure this program exists, but I don't remember what it was called.

There are a few drop-down terminal programs (guake, yakuke, tilde), and I've been a fan of guake for a while. However, since I discovered GNU Screen I've been more interested in using Eterm. But I would like to make it dropdown/hide on keypress, similar to the way Guake does. I remember at some point that someone mentioned a program that allowed you to do similar things with basically any other window.

Unfortunately my time spent googling around for terms like "show/hide any terminal ubuntu" have been met with stupid Windows search engine spam.

Any clue where I could find the program I'm looking for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic search phrase is "quake-like terminal".  More specifically, I searched for "[arbitrary quake-like terminal gnome](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=arbitrary%20quake-like%20terminal%20gnome&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)" and the top several hits demonstrate [several](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/how-to-get-quake-like-terminal-under.html) [ways](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1066090) of doing it.  (They claim to be specific to Terminator and `gnome-terminal` respectively, but in fact can be adapted to any terminal program, or indeed almost any program you choose.)  The first method requires Compiz.

Comment: Perfect! The compiz version works perfectly for me and is exactly what I wanted. Thank!